# update multiple columns with one condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have one table with some columns and I need to update it on conditional basis in SQL server.
I have one table and I wanted to execute the 'Update' statement on this table after some UI operation.
But the thing is I have to update only some columns on a condition basis and some columns will be updated without any condition.

Please check the schema details below

**Table_1**

| ID | Name | Email | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | a@g.com | 12345678890 |
| 2 | B | b@g.com | 14345678890 |

I have one procedure where we are sending the parameters for updating this table and we are also sending one flag parameter (for applying the condition in update statement)

```
CREATE PROC UpdateStudent                    
 @Name VARCHAR(100) = NULL,                    
 @Email VARCHAR(100) = NULL,                 
 @Phone VARCHAR(20) = NULL,                   
 @IsChanged BIT = NULL 
AS                   
BEGIN                         
           
      --update 'Table_1'
      update Table_1 SET 
                 Name = IIF(@IsChanged = 1, @Name, null),
                 Email = @Email,
                 Phone = IIF(@IsChanged = 1, @Phone , null)
      where ID = 1
END
```

So if flag @IsChanged is 1 then as per the above query I need to update but if flag @IsChanged is 0 then I have to update different 'Update' statement-

```
  IF @IsChanged = 0
  BEGIN
              --update 'Table_1'
                update Table_1 SET 
                    Name = NULL,
                    Email = NULL,
                    Phone = NULL
               where ID = 1

  END
```

Is there any best way to handle this requirement where if we have to update multiple columns with one condition, how we can do that in SQL server?

Comment: What is wrong with your current update query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, nothing wrong, but the thing is if I have 10 columns in my table then I have to use this condition 10 times for each columns. So, I am looking for a way where we can use one case statement or one condition only to update it.

Comment: You could replace `IIF` with a `CASE` expression, but it would actually give you more code, not less.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, will it resolve my problem? If yes please add some code.

Comment: No - there is no "problem" to solve here. You are simply trying to avoid writing repetitive code. Asking others to do it for you for free seems more than a bit presumptuous. And I think your current design and logic make no sense. If nothing has changed (IsChanged = 0), then why would this procedure be called? And default values of null for a procedure like this make no sense IMO but do encourage developer laziness.

Comment: Just have 2 updates, one for the columns that must be updated regardless, and one that runs conditionally. Put the conditional update in its own procedure and call it from your `if`, that way both should get an optimal execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

To make things more clear, you can have IF else logic.

```sql
IF @IsChanged = 1 
BEGIN 
update Table_1 SET 
                 Name = @Name
                 Email = @Email,
                 Phone = @Phone
      where ID = 1
END
ELSE
BEGIN
update Table_1 SET 
                 Name = null
                 Email = @Email,
                 Phone =  null
      where ID = 1
END
```